# JavaFX Application UI stops updating on moving cursor out of the window

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I created a small JavaFX based music player with material Design features. It works fine but the problem is that the Seek stops updating after 3 seconds when i move the cursor out of the window. Why is this happening? Can anyone help?

dashboardController.java
:

```
package lyrica;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXProgressBar;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSlider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author debayan
 */
public class dashboardController implements Initializable {

static boolean isSongAlreadyPlaying = false;
static boolean isSongAsigned = false;
static boolean isSeekBeingChanged = false;
static String currentSongName = "";
static String currentAlbumName = "";
static String currentArtistName = "";
static Double currentSongDuration = 0.00;


static int currentSongIndex = 0;

MediaPlayer player = null;
@FXML
private JFXButton pauseStartButton;

@FXML
private JFXProgressBar pBarLoading;

@FXML
private JFXSlider songSeek;

@FXML
private JFXButton previousButton;

@FXML
private JFXButton nextButton;

@FXML
private Label albumLabel;

@FXML
private Label loadingMusicFilesLabel;

@FXML
private Label itsLonelyHereLabel;

@FXML
private JFXButton checkForSongsButton;

@FXML
private Label itsLonelyHere2Label;

@FXML
private JFXListView songListview;

@FXML
private Label songNameLabel;

@FXML
private JFXButton stopButton;

@FXML
private Label currentMusicLocationLabel;

@FXML
private Label totalMusicInfoLabel;
 String fileNameAttr = "file://";
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{

    if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux"))
    {
        fileNameAttr = "file://";
    }
    else
    {
        fileNameAttr = "file:///";
    }
    try
    {
        searchForSongs();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

refreshSeek();



}    

public void refreshSeek()
{



Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() {
            while(true)
        {



            if(songSeek.isValueChanging())
        {
            double newSongTime = ((songSeek.getValue()/100)*currentSongDuration)*60000;
            player.seek(Duration.millis(newSongTime));
        }
            else
        {
            if(isSongAsigned)
        {
            console.pln("asd");
            double currentSongCurrentSeek = player.getCurrentTime().toMinutes();

            double seekProgress = (currentSongCurrentSeek/currentSongDuration)*100;

            songSeek.setValue(seekProgress);
        }
        }



            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}

@FXML
public void searchForSongs() throws IOException
{
    pBarLoading.setOpacity(1);
    loadingMusicFilesLabel.setOpacity(1);

    try 
    {
        File folder = new File(Lyrica.songDirectory);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        int i;
        int tmpNoOfSongs = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<listOfFiles.length ; i++)
        {
            if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            {
                String tmpFileNameExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                if (tmpFileNameExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3"))
                {

                    Lyrica.songList.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    tmpNoOfSongs++;
                }
            }
        }

        Lyrica.noOfSongs = tmpNoOfSongs;
        console.pln(Integer.toString(Lyrica.noOfSongs));
        console.pln("Song Names : ");
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<Lyrica.songList.size(); j++)
        {
            console.pln(Lyrica.songList.get(j).toString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pBarLoading.setOpacity(0);
    loadingMusicFilesLabel.setOpacity(0);

    if(Lyrica.noOfSongs == 0)
    {
        itsLonelyHereLabel.setOpacity(1);
        itsLonelyHere2Label.setOpacity(1);
        checkForSongsButton.setOpacity(1);
        itsLonelyHere2Label.setText("We were not able to search for songs in '"+Lyrica.songDirectory+"' ...\nPlease copy some songs over there");
    }
    else
    {
        checkForSongsButton.setDisable(true);
        songListview.getItems().clear();
        songListview.getItems().add("Song Name");
        int k;
        for(k=0; k<Lyrica.songList.size(); k++)
        {
            String nameToBeAdded = Lyrica.songList.get(k).toString().replace(".mp3","");
            nameToBeAdded = nameToBeAdded.replace(".MP3", "");
            songListview.getItems().add(nameToBeAdded);
        }
        songListview.setOpacity(1);
    }
}

@FXML
public void playSelectedSong()
{
    int selected = (songListview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() - 1);
    if(selected != -1)
    {

        console.pln("SELECTED : "+Lyrica.songList.get(selected));
        playSong(Lyrica.songDirectory+"/"+Lyrica.songList.get(selected), Lyrica.songList.get(selected).toString(), selected);
    }


}

public void playSong(String fileName,String fileNameWithoutLocation, int songIndex)
{

    currentSongIndex = songIndex;
    pauseStartButton.setText("Pause");
    songSeek.setOpacity(1);
    previousButton.setOpacity(1);
    nextButton.setOpacity(1);
    pauseStartButton.setOpacity(1);
    stopButton.setOpacity(1);
    String fname = "asds";

    try
    {
        String songName = fileName;
        String songNameToBeProcessed = "";
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<songName.length(); i++)
        {
            if(songName.charAt(i) == '/' )
            {
                songNameToBeProcessed += "/";
            }
            else if(Character.toString(songName.charAt(i)).equals("\\"))
            {
                songNameToBeProcessed += Character.toString(songName.charAt(i));
            }
            else
            {
                if(songName.charAt(i) == ' ')
                {
                    songNameToBeProcessed += "%20";
                }
                else
                {
                    songNameToBeProcessed+=URLEncoder.encode(Character.toString(songName.charAt(i)), "UTF-8");
                }

            }
        }
        fname = songNameToBeProcessed;
        console.pln(fname);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    console.pln("asdasd");

    Media pick = new Media(fileNameAttr+fname);

    String tmpcurrentSongName = fileNameWithoutLocation.replace(".mp3","");
    currentSongName = tmpcurrentSongName.replace(".MP3","");


    if(isSongAlreadyPlaying)
    {
        player.stop();
    }
    player = null;
    boolean wasAvailable = false;
    try
    {
        player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
        wasAvailable = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        console.pln("Unable to play music file...");
        wasAvailable = false;
    }



    player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    nextButtonClicked();
}
});

    player.setOnReady(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String tmpTitle = tmpcurrentSongName;
        String tmpAlbum = "Unknown";

        currentSongDuration = pick.getDuration().toMinutes();
        double thisSongDuration = pick.getDuration().toMinutes();
        String thisSongDurationString = Double.toString(thisSongDuration);
    int x;
    String finalDurationToBeShown = "";
    boolean didPointCome = false;
    for(x = 0;x<thisSongDurationString.length();x++)
    {


        if(Character.toString(thisSongDurationString.charAt(x)).equals("."))
        {
            didPointCome = true;
            finalDurationToBeShown += ":";
            finalDurationToBeShown += Character.toString(thisSongDurationString.charAt(x+1));
            finalDurationToBeShown += Character.toString(thisSongDurationString.charAt(x+2));
            break;
        }

        if(didPointCome == false)
        {
            finalDurationToBeShown += Character.toString(thisSongDurationString.charAt(x));
        }
    }


    console.pln(finalDurationToBeShown);
    totalMusicInfoLabel.setText(finalDurationToBeShown);
    totalMusicInfoLabel.setOpacity(1);
        console.pln("Song Duration :"+currentSongDuration);
        try
        {
            tmpTitle = pick.getMetadata().get("title").toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tmpTitle = tmpcurrentSongName;
        }

        try
        {
            tmpAlbum = pick.getMetadata().get("album").toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tmpAlbum = "Unknown";
        }

        refreshSongInfo(tmpTitle, tmpAlbum);
        console.pln(pick.getMetadata().toString());
    }
});
    player.play();
    isSongAlreadyPlaying = true;
    isSongAsigned = true;
}

@FXML
public void pauseStartButtonClicked(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(isSongAlreadyPlaying)
    {
        pauseStartButton.setText("Resume");
        isSongAlreadyPlaying = false;
        player.pause();
    }
    else
    {
        if(isSongAsigned)
        {
            pauseStartButton.setText("Pause");
            player.play();
            isSongAlreadyPlaying = true;
        }
    }
}

public void refreshSongInfo(String titlePassed, String albumPassed)
{
    songNameLabel.setText(titlePassed);
    albumLabel.setText(albumPassed);
}

@FXML
public void stopButtonClicked(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(isSongAsigned)
    {
        player.stop();
        player = null;
        isSongAlreadyPlaying = false;
        isSongAsigned = false;

        songSeek.setOpacity(0);
        previousButton.setOpacity(0);
        nextButton.setOpacity(0);
        pauseStartButton.setOpacity(0);
        stopButton.setOpacity(0);
        pauseStartButton.setText("Start");
        refreshSongInfo("Select A Song","To Be Played");
    }
}

@FXML
public void quitButtonClicked(ActionEvent event)
{
    console.pln("Quitting...");
    System.exit(0);
}

@FXML
public void selectAnotherSongDirectory(ActionEvent event)
{
    new mentionSongDirectory().setVisible(true);
    Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
    Stage s= (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
    s.close();
}

@FXML
public void nextButtonClicked()
{
    int newSongIndex;
    String newSong;
    String songDirectory;
    if(currentSongIndex == Lyrica.songList.size() - 1)
    {
        // index 1
        newSongIndex = 0;
        newSong = Lyrica.songList.get(newSongIndex).toString();
        songDirectory = Lyrica.songDirectory;
    }
    else
    {
        newSongIndex = currentSongIndex +1;
        newSong = Lyrica.songList.get(newSongIndex).toString();
        songDirectory = Lyrica.songDirectory;
    }
    console.pln("NEXT BUTTON CLICKED");
    playSong(songDirectory+"/"+newSong,newSong,newSongIndex);
    songListview.getSelectionModel().select(newSongIndex+1);
    songListview.getFocusModel().focus(newSongIndex+1);
    songListview.scrollTo(newSongIndex+1);
}


@FXML
public void previousButtonClicked()
{
    int newSongIndex;
    String newSong;
    String songDirectory;
    if(currentSongIndex == 0)
    {
        // index 1
        newSongIndex = Lyrica.songList.size() - 1;
        newSong = Lyrica.songList.get(newSongIndex).toString();
        songDirectory = Lyrica.songDirectory;
    }
    else
    {
        newSongIndex = currentSongIndex -1;
        newSong = Lyrica.songList.get(newSongIndex).toString();
        songDirectory = Lyrica.songDirectory;
    }
    console.pln("PREVIOUS BUTTON CLICKED");
    playSong(songDirectory+"/"+newSong,newSong,newSongIndex);
    songListview.getSelectionModel().select(newSongIndex+1);
    songListview.getFocusModel().focus(newSongIndex+1);
    songListview.scrollTo(newSongIndex+1);
}


@FXML
public void aboutButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws Exception
{
    if(player != null)
    {
        player.stop();
        isSongAsigned = false;
        isSongAlreadyPlaying = false;
    }
    new openFXML("about.fxml",true,event);
}

}
```

dashboard.fxml

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXProgressBar?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSlider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="590.0" prefWidth="995.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="lyrica.dashboardController">
   <children>
      <JFXListView fx:id="songListview" layoutY="52.0"     onMouseClicked="#playSelectedSong" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="454.0" prefWidth="999.0" />
      <AnchorPane layoutX="-2.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="1001.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7c43bd;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="18.0" layoutY="12.0" text="Gramophy" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="21.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <JFXButton fx:id="quitButton" layoutX="960.0" layoutY="12.0" onAction="#quitButtonClicked" ripplerFill="RED" text="X" textFill="RED" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="aboutButton" layoutX="925.0" layoutY="12.0" onAction="#aboutButtonClicked" ripplerFill="#00c7ff" text="i" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
           </font>
        </JFXButton>
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  <AnchorPane layoutY="506.0" prefHeight="84.0" prefWidth="999.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7c43bd;">
     <children>
        <Label fx:id="songNameLabel" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="352.0" text="Select A Song" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="19.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <JFXButton fx:id="pauseStartButton" layoutX="756.0" layoutY="36.0" onAction="#pauseStartButtonClicked" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="Resume" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="17.0" />
           </font></JFXButton>
        <JFXSlider fx:id="songSeek" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="13.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="520.0" />
        <JFXButton fx:id="nextButton" layoutX="867.0" layoutY="36.0" onAction="#nextButtonClicked" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Next" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="17.0" />
           </font></JFXButton>
        <JFXButton fx:id="previousButton" layoutX="630.0" layoutY="36.0" onAction="#previousButtonClicked" opacity="0.0" text="Previous" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="17.0" />
           </font>
        </JFXButton>
        <Label fx:id="albumLabel" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="46.0" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="352.0" text="To Be Played" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="15.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <JFXButton fx:id="stopButton" layoutX="549.0" layoutY="36.0" onAction="#stopButtonClicked" opacity="0.0" text="Stop" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="17.0" />
           </font>
        </JFXButton>
        <Label fx:id="currentMusicLocationLabel" layoutX="375.0" layoutY="14.0" opacity="0.0" text="0:00" textFill="WHITE" />
        <Label fx:id="totalMusicInfoLabel" layoutX="940.0" layoutY="14.0" opacity="0.0" text="0:00" textFill="WHITE" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  <JFXProgressBar fx:id="pBarLoading" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="202.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="427.0" />
  <Label fx:id="loadingMusicFilesLabel" layoutX="276.0" layoutY="215.0" opacity="0.0" text="Loading music Files..." />
  <Label fx:id="itsLonelyHereLabel" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="57.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="283.0" text="Its Lonely Here...">
     <font>
        <Font size="32.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
        <Label fx:id="itsLonelyHere2Label" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="97.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="452.0" text="We were not able to search for songs in DIRECTORY ...&#10;Please copy some songs over there&#10;&#10;You can also set a different location to search for songs :" />
        <JFXButton fx:id="checkForSongsButton" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="137.0" onAction="#selectAnotherSongDirectory" opacity="0.0" ripplerFill="BLACK" text="Set Another Song Directory" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: More information like a code snippet might help

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which explains how to best ask a question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @IvoVidovic i added the code snippet